# CustomAlertView buttons not Visible in ios 8

Tags: ios8, sdcalertview

I am using  [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView)
 for custom alertview. It is perfectly working in ios 7 . But in ios8 alertview button are not visible . i am not able find actual problem .

[image]

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: please provide sample code for SDCAlertView code downloaded from iven link not show link error while build in iOS8

Comment: here is code https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView

Comment: When i download and built project in iOS8 it show an linking error

Comment: you have to follow all  steps for installation ...

Answer (score 0):

I had absolutely same problem. So I've created test project to reproduce it. And I couldn't. It was working in small test program.

So I've just updated my project's pods. Just use `pod update` and rebuild your project. Most likely you have outdated version of `SDCAlertView`.